# Blank Report Displaying in any format in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a report and exporting in html format report. But when i run it it displays a blank screen while it create a html page, when I open the html page it also shows a blank page. below is my code.

```
JasperReport jasperReport;
        JasperPrint jasperPrint;
        JasperDesign jasperdesign;

        //jasperdesign = JasperManager.loadXmlDesign("D:/Tutorials&Lectures/IReport/report1.jrxml");
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("D:/Tutorials&Lectures/IReport/report1.jrxml");
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null);
        //JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, "D:/reports/testReport.html" );
        JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,"D:/Tutorials&Lectures/IReport/testReport.html");
        exporter.exportReport();
```

what else i am missing.

Comment: I have found the solution, by giving an new JREmptyDataSource() in fillReport and it worked.